# Inverse Trig & Trig Sub

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Can someone explain to me how to solve this using inverse trig and trig sub?

$$\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\, dx$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hyperbolic substitution, i.e. let $x=\sinh t$ then
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\, dx&=\int \sinh^3 t\, dt\\
&=\int (\cosh^2t -1)\sinh t\, dt\\
&=\frac{\cosh^3 t}{3}-\cosh t+C\\
&=\frac{(\sqrt{1+x^2})^3}{3}-\sqrt{1+x^2}+C
\end{align*}
Also you can use triangle substitution : $x=\tan \theta$
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\, dx&=\int \tan^3\theta\sec\theta\, d\theta\\
&=\int (\sec^2\theta-1)\sec\theta\tan\theta\, d\theta\\
&=\frac{\sec^3\theta}{3}-\sec\theta+C\\
&=\frac{(\sqrt{1+x^2})^3}{3}-\sqrt{1+x^2}+C
\end{align*}

Comment: How do you explain the different results?

Comment: I have a mistake I've corrected, thanks for your comment.

Comment: How did u know to plug in tan theta? Tan is A^2 + x^2, but there is a square root over that.

Comment: Dear @user113113; Indeed when you have $\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$ it will be useful. Since $a^2+x^2=a^2sec^2\theta$ square root will be omitted.

Answer (score 4):

Set $u=1+x^2$. Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=2x$ and so,

$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=\int \dfrac12\dfrac{u-1}{\sqrt{u}}du=\dfrac12\int (u^{1/2}-u^{-1/2})\, du$.

Comment: nice observation (+1)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{x^3+x-x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Set $1+x^2=u$ in each case

Comment: $\dfrac{x^3+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ doesn't simplify to $x\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: @Alraxite, thanks for your observation.  Wrong calculation made things unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use integration by part: let $u=x^2$ and $dv=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ then you will have:
\begin{align*}
\int udv&=uv-\int vdu\\
&=x^2\sqrt{1+x^2}-\int2x\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=x^2\sqrt{1+x^2}-\frac{2}{3}(1+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C
\end{align*}
where the last integral was solved by substitution $\ u=1+x^2$

Comment: $$v=\sqrt{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Your comment is appreciated @Ron Gordon.